# How to model this multivariate longitudinal data?

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, multinomial-distribution, copula

Let $x = (x_{t_0}, x_{t_1}, \ldots, x_{t_s})$, where $x_{t_j}$ is a $d$-dimensional ordinal vector taking values in $\{0,\ldots, K\}^d$ measured at time point $t_j$.

There is correlation between the elements of each vector and also since this a repeated measurement experiment over time, there should be also correlation between different time points. If there was only one measurement, I would model $x$ as a copula multinomial, but now that we have multiple measurements, how should I model $x$?

Answer (score 2):

You can see in Chapter "Joint Models for High-Dimensional Longitudinal Data" of this [book](https://www.routledge.com/Longitudinal-Data-Analysis/Fitzmaurice-Davidian-Verbeke-Molenberghs/p/book/9781584886587) an excellent overview of statistical modes that can be used for your setting. I take here an example. Suppose that you model each (longitudinal) response (the $k^{th}$ response) by a random intercept model, i.e.,
$$y_{ijk} = ... + b_{ik} + \varepsilon_{ijk},$$
where $b_{ik}$ is the random intercept. If no further assumption/model is made, the responses are independent. To model their association, one way is to specify a numtivariate distribution for $\boldsymbol{b}_i = (b_{i1}, ..., b_{iK})^T\sim N(0, D)$ where $D$ is a variance-covariance matrix.

[Pairwise approach](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16918906/) might be useful when $K$ (the number of response) is large.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the book. Data is discrete so I don't think normal distribution would be useful in this case.

Comment: In that chapter, they also talk about the case of discrete outcomes.